# Laravel giving different controller to the same Get route

Tags: php, laravel, controller, get, routes

When I click to a button on the page, I want some functions to be performed and turn back to the page again.

```
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@team')->name('team');
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@makeOwner')->name('make-owner');
```

I have my routes like this.When I try to go blade I get this error.

```
"Route [team] not defined. (View: /var/www/resources/views/teams.blade.php)"
```

How can I solve this error or any suggestion to perform this in a better way?

Comment: Are these in a route group?  Using `artisan route:list` is a good way to view all registered routes.

Comment: In your case only second route is registered.

Comment: Davit is right, didn't realize you were using the same URI and method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@team')->name('team');
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@makeOwner')->name('make-owner');
```

**When you use same method ans same uri in route only last route is registered**.This case only second route is registered. You must be change your routes  . Or in view use `route('make-owner')` instead of `route('team')`.
It is more good to change routes for example

```
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@team')->name('team');
Route::get('/team/{team}/make-owner', 'HomeController@makeOwner')->name('make-owner');
```

Or change one route method for example  one `get` second `put`

```
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@team')->name('team');
Route::put('/team/{team}', 'HomeController@makeOwner')->name('make-owner');
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the same URI?

Comment: Two routes with some method and same uri you can not, instaed you can one `get` one `post` method

Comment: Maybe I can tell what I am trying to do then you can give an idea.

Comment: Yes tell what do you want do

Comment: There is a page called team and there are some users on the page. I put a link button next to each user. When clicked to button, that user will be a manager role then the same team page will reload.

Comment: You can in HomeController call one method to other. For example `pubilc   function makeOwner () {$this->team($arguments); ...}` or `pubilc   function team () {$this->makeOwner($arguments); ...}`

Comment: Also you can use `get-put` methods(last part of answer) and the HomeController@makeOwner methot use `return redirect()->route('team');`. See documntation [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirecting-named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirecting-named-routes)